# How can I decrypt an "encrypted string with java" in c sharp?

Tags: c#, java, android, encryption, rsa

I have a string. That encrypted with java. Now I have to decrypt it in c sharp.

I use RSA algorithm with same public/private keys in c sharp and java.

But in decryption with c sharp I got a "Bad Data" error.

and an important notice is that: I can decrypt this string in java!  and I can encrypt with c sharp and decrypt with c sharp !! But when I try to encrypt with one of them(c sharp or java) and decrypt with the other one it raise an error !

this is my c sharp code :

```
string privateKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>rFsMn+idg8jmVMk249DzJc7AFft3+/jcnYDTh9wHee3tgFu1gBRh7e+ao+MWq7NEN0N7kUHa7O4c/ND2Ahcx/h4mXD5KDoixFRBUsxYqCJVA68qYJ7vozVPMjNr4jeOo1xt+oevO5+mUWtcaib5Iw51u1Jq/6qCqLsm8Eq3cnsE=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>5aqTyz3GH655H+vO/BzJvFzpILpxLwXZEvqp3l3NYXKqP0tdkY1g36o6M9YodI3h8ho4VFYofIqA1+V0qPkuDQ==</P><Q>wB45uljBS8Z+WGRE1cRdpZb5aKUv76uLlCp6agtPBBhjXNIQrN8MpOCTvZM2cOsuYpYhDtnwsTY9KKXdBmv6hQ==</Q><DP>KB474uzPhwk7L1BJv9BnjPfN4WGwE765xI70zVslXThidNv9ZEeF/IwHzrZCKtn99gSOgmzqdZbcGtqCHmIooQ==</DP><DQ>eLnFrvsdJJ/sP2Fq/CX0bx0rR34eXG6hPI9g84h9s+YbcnWy8t8LVASn8oYyvMydDminB20e2k1qK0PnW6S4/Q==</DQ><InverseQ>rlPpLse8LJ0KRglnu2D1xzJT90QqzS3o80P0WTpUvm95mF5d8YaVj/d9W7FBdgZ98y6Q7of+wLCmYGKLg56wYQ==</InverseQ><D>Gs8mzZDPP3p2aWXLBfCwgYcBVeoBpc318wHg5VcSSqL5uGeLedqxyOLmOOvP0PFXgQkcJWIK/aOkGqcePQECo3TNiK+uLSwc97V3spZah70FFJVyh23Y+o0wlRGHAm5Nj9QieHlVwhgJPkNUJYgH9qkwB9aCpl+rdAG3da2fQ2E=</D></RSAKeyValue>";
string publicKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>rFsMn+idg8jmVMk249DzJc7AFft3+/jcnYDTh9wHee3tgFu1gBRh7e+ao+MWq7NEN0N7kUHa7O4c/ND2Ahcx/h4mXD5KDoixFRBUsxYqCJVA68qYJ7vozVPMjNr4jeOo1xt+oevO5+mUWtcaib5Iw51u1Jq/6qCqLsm8Eq3cnsE=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";



public string EncryptData(string data2Encrypt )
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.FromXmlString(publicKey);
    byte[] plainbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data2Encrypt);
    byte[] cipherbytes = rsa.Encrypt(plainbytes, false);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherbytes);
}

public string DecryptData(string data2Decrypt)
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsa.FromXmlString(privateKey);
    byte[] plainbytes = rsa.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(data2Decrypt), false);
    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainbytes);
}
```

and my java code is :

```
byte[] expBytes = Base64.decode("AQAB".getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] modBytes = Base64.decode("rFsMn+idg8jmVMk249DzJc7AFft3+/jcnYDTh9wHee3tgFu1gBRh7e+ao+MWq7NEN0N7kUHa7O4c/ND2Ahcx/h4mXD5KDoixFRBUsxYqCJVA68qYJ7vozVPMjNr4jeOo1xt+oevO5+mUWtcaib5Iw51u1Jq/6qCqLsm8Eq3cnsE=".getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
byte[] dBytes = Base64.decode("Gs8mzZDPP3p2aWXLBfCwgYcBVeoBpc318wHg5VcSSqL5uGeLedqxyOLmOOvP0PFXgQkcJWIK/aOkGqcePQECo3TNiK+uLSwc97V3spZah70FFJVyh23Y+o0wlRGHAm5Nj9QieHlVwhgJPkNUJYgH9qkwB9aCpl+rdAG3da2fQ2E=".getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);

BigInteger modules = new BigInteger(1, modBytes);
BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, expBytes);
BigInteger d = new BigInteger(1, dBytes);

KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
String input = "test";

RSAPublicKeySpec pubSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modules, exponent);
PublicKey pubKey = factory.generatePublic(pubSpec);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(input.getBytes());

String strEncrypted = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

I can not decode **strEncrypted** value in c sharp.

and at the end encryption value in java is different with c sharp(same keys and algorithm and data) !!!

Comment: To start, have you verified in the debugger that you're getting the same `byte[]` values from your Base64 methods? Which `Base64` is that in Java?

Comment: How do you transfer the ciphertext from one system to the other? How big is your ciphertext?

Comment: @chrylis Actually i'm using **android.util.Base64**

Comment: The outcome of encryption should be different for each encrypt (think of what happens if you send either "yes" or "no" multiple times to the same receipient). RSA encryption uses secure random padding values. The only way to test is to decrypt.

Comment: In c sharp I get a different string per every call encrypt method. But it's not true about java!!!
in java I get the same string for every time !!!
I dizzied :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it :)

I changed this line :

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
```

to :

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1PADDING");
```

It worked well. But who knows what's different between these ?

Answer (score 3):

Second parameter of `RSACryptoServiceProvider.Encrypt(plainbytes, false)` means that PKCS#1 padding is used. `true` is for OAEP padding.

In Java the security provider you use maps `"RSA"` to `"RSA/ECB/NoPadding"`, which is just encryption without any padding, hence an encryption result is always the same. So there is a need to specify `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` to match C# behavior.

You should always specify the mode and padding otherwise the security provider will choose it's own defaults - and the defaults may differ for each provider.